# How to implement swipe gesture in android

Tags: java, android, swipe-gesture

I am new to Android. Here, I want to implement Swipe Gesture to navigate between Activities. I have googled it and found different answers in different sites. But I could not get the exact point. 
By reading all of them I got that we need to implement `onTouchEvent()` and `onFlingEvent()`.

Are these functions enough to implement the Swipe action?
Please specify on How to proceed step wise to implement swipe gesture.

I am sorry if I asked you a very simple question as I have asked this question after a long long try of many code snippets.

Can any one please clear my doubt?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - basic gesture detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`onTouchEvent` is enough. What you want to do is:

- Create a `VelocityTracker` and feed it the
  touch results from the view.
- When you get a UP event, check what the velocity was. If its more
  than some threshold amount in the X direction, that counts as a
  swipe.
- Start a new activity when you recognize it.

You'll likely have to play with the threshold a bit, otherwise a sloppy tap could be mistaken for a swipe.

Comment: you should also provide, some sample code for reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to swipe your view then you should use `ViewFlipper` You can set a `onTouchListener` on ViewFlipper. And you can register `GestureDetector` in onTouchListener. Here is one good example for that [Android transitions- slide in and slide out](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/07/android-transistions-slide-in-and-slide.html).