# I want to make custome keyboard. Anyone know library for gesture typing on custom keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, gesture

I want a library for gesture typing like SwiftKey keyboard or google keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is two-fold:

1- Implementing a custom keyboard. This question has been asked before here, but you can check out this post with some sample code: http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm

2- Implementing the swipe gesture. This is even more complicated, as you would have to create your onTouchListener, and draw some kind of animation when the screen is touched. You could start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435088/how-to-implement-swipe-gesture-in-android)